# How can I change the font color of a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have used setAdapter method into insert text to the ListView. I can't find a way to change the font color in the ListView. Google search gives me results which they have used TextView with a ListView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".viewnotesActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/notes_list"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"/>
/>
```

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,layout,list);
    ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.notes_list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)view;
            String note = tv.getText().toString();
            String file = data.get(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(viewnotesActivity.this,editnoteActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("note",note);
            intent.putExtra("file",file);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to create a custom adapter to customize these stuffs

Comment: I can't find an answer from it. It has used a TextView also

Comment: you can add custom TextView layout in your adapter.
Can you show me your layout ?in which you are using TextView ?

Comment: I don't have a TextView

Comment: @shayanmalinda You should add your ListItem layout to the question.